# recidect 301 from oldsite.altervista.org to network.net/site

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a huge problem. my site runs on altervista service ( similar to wordpress.com ) and I have constructed a new website using a multisite wordpress installation.

Now I need to redirect 301 all the content from the old site to the new one in the multisite. I tried different htaccess codes but I get only the homepage to redirect.

So I need to redirect from oldsite.altervista.org to network.net/site how can I do that?

I tried this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite.altervista.org$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://network.net/site/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: 1 guess I have: are there capital letters ? Then you need to ad [NC] in your RewriteCond

Comment: it looks correct but does not work! only the home page gets redirected...

Comment: What happens to the other pages? Do they not get redirected at all or all to the homepage?

Comment: the other pages don't get redirected at all, so i see all the posts/pages from the old site..

Comment: Can you access the new page directly? (I think of multiple redirects)... Where have u placed the htaccess there should already be one from WordPress have u replaced it? (But first make a backup of it ofc)

Comment: no i can access the new page directly via the old home pahe. i have placed my code under all the other code placed by wordpress.

Comment: Your rule must be the first!! Else the WordPress rules will match first and your rule never gets applied because of the [L] flag in the WordPress code

Comment: sure? my actual code is: # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# # av:php5-engine
AddHandler av-php5 .php

php_value post_max_size 20M
php_value upload_max_filesize 20M

# # av:Toolbar
SetEnv AV_TOOLBAR 1
Do i have to put my code before this code?

Comment: so i have to put my code between RewriteBase / and RewriteRule ^index\.php ?

Comment: You should place it before # WordPress begin

Comment: ok! i will try it and let you know! Thanks!

Comment: ok it works! Thanks a lot!